# rails has_many through undefined method `body' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have models

```
class Riskfactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bodies_riskfactors
  has_many :bodies, through: :bodies_riskfactors    
end

class Body < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bodies_riskfactors
  has_many :riskfactors, through: :bodies_riskfactors   
end

class DisordersArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :disorder
  belongs_to :article   
end
```

---

in view

```
= form_for [:admin, @riskfactor], html: {role: "form"} do |f|
  = f.select :body_ids, Body.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true
```

and I have error on update

What could be wrong?

```
Processing by Admin::RiskfactorsController#update as HTML
```

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CVkdBHLzLAeQ8FRFBVyonUuyn1FZAYG+X9fX/mmj+Bo=", "riskfactor"=>{"body_ids"=>["", "1"], "position"=>"1", "slug"=>"risk-factor-2", "name_ru"=>"High Blood Pressure", "published_ru"=>"no", "content_ru"=>"", "meta_description_ru"=>"", "meta_keywords_ru"=>"", "name_en"=>"High Blood Pressure", "published_en"=>"no", "content_en"=>"

High Blood Pressure High Blood Pressure High Blood Pressure High Blood Pressure High Blood Pressure

", "meta_description_en"=>"", "meta_keywords_en"=>""}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Riskfactor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `riskfactors`.* FROM `riskfactors` WHERE `riskfactors`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Body Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `bodies`.* FROM `bodies` WHERE `bodies`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY position LIMIT 1
  Body Load (2.6ms)  SELECT `bodies`.* FROM `bodies` INNER JOIN `bodies_riskfactors` ON `bodies`.`id` = `bodies_riskfactors`.`body_id` WHERE `bodies_riskfactors`.`riskfactor_id` = 4 ORDER BY position
  Riskfactor::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `riskfactor_translations`.* FROM `riskfactor_translations` WHERE `riskfactor_translations`.`riskfactor_id` = 4
  Riskfactor Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `riskfactors` WHERE (`riskfactors`.`slug` = 'risk-factor-2' AND `riskfactors`.`id` != 4) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `body' for #<Riskfactor:0x007f9a0351c350>):
  app/controllers/admin/riskfactors_controller.rb:45:in`block in update'
  app/controllers/admin/riskfactors_controller.rb:44:in `update'

RiskfactorsController

```
class Admin::RiskfactorsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :set_riskfactor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @riskfactor.update(riskfactor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [:edit, :admin, @riskfactor], notice: 'Riskfactor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
       else
         format.html { render action: 'edit' }
         format.json { render json: @riskfactor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end


  private
    def set_riskfactor
      @riskfactor = Riskfactor.find(params[:id])
    end

    def riskfactor_params
      params.require(:riskfactor).permit!
    end
end
```

Comment: Post error message also.

Comment: Post the riskfasctors_controller.rb also, at least the update part.

Comment: Does Risfactor has a field named body ? That's what error message is saying.

Comment: You are using a `has_many ... through` relation, so the foreign keys are on the `through` table (`bodies_riskfactors`).

Answer (score 0):

Imho the problem is that you have `body_ids` in your view, but you named you association as `bodies`. Try to rename `body_ids` to `bodies_ids` or something like that.

Comment: undefined method `bodies_ids' for #<Riskfactor:0x007f9a023971c0>

Comment: The error has nothing to do wassociationsith association.  Check your schema to see you have your columns right

Comment: I am quite sure it's related. When Rails will see something like `something_ids` it will try to look for a relation `something` using method missing pattern. It's all about providing the right association name to comply with the convention of `something_ids`. Maybe it should be `bodies_riskfactors_ids`, like one commenter suggested.

Comment: Sorry! In model Riskfactor I have wrong: validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:body] <--- body doesn't have